# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\yo\index.php on line 3

Tags: php, html

I am new on php and i am trying to add this code

Im finding this error please any one who can solve this for me

```
<?php
$myName = ‘Guest’;
$myVar = “Welcome back $myName”;
echo $myVar;
?>
```

This is my html

```
<p><?php echo $myVar; ?></p>
```

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you are using left and right quotes, try retyping that in a plain text editor like Notepad (Windows), TextEdit (Mac), or gedit (linux). That way it will have normal quotes, e.g. `"`. Note: In TextEdit you will need to press Cmd+Shift+T to make it plain text.

Comment: yes thanks so much.. i was using wordpad thanks so much i will get some good php editor as you said thanks so much

Comment: @DeepakKumar If you don't want to go all out and use an IDE, I found that TextPad is a great basic editor to work with. Allows multiple files open at once, can do syntax highlighting and has line numbering. You really don't want too much else to start with.

Comment: @Fluffeh Thanks for telling me i will get it now

Comment: [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org) is the absolute best text editor.

Comment: Thanks @ShaquinTrifonoff i will try it as well and find best for me thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are using funny quotes rather than the straight ' and " types.

```
<?php
$myName = 'Guest';
$myVar = "Welcome back $myName";
echo $myVar;
?>
```

Comment: for adding help ( in my case - I forgot the ( ; ) semicolon on the previous line )

Answer (score 1):

you need to write

```
$myVar = "Welcome Back $myName";
```

the problem is that you are using the wrong char for the quote character

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $myName = "Guest";
    $myVar = "Welcome back ".$myName;
    echo $myVar;
?>
```

or

```
<?php
    $myName = "Guest";
    $myVar = "Welcome back $myName";
    echo $myVar;
?>
```

This is how code works while concatenating the string.

Answer (score 0):

Write `$myVar = “Welcome back" . $myName;` instead `$myVar = “Welcome back $myName";`

```
<?php
$myName = ‘Guest’;
$myVar = “Welcome back" . $myName;
echo $myVar;
?>
```